# Is it possible for a debian package to be installed by multiple names through apt?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, packaging, deb

I have a package `foo-new`, which many new users know by its old name `foo-old`, so they try to execute `apt install foo-old` which does not work.

Is it possible through a control field to make a package being installed through either name from apt, so both

```
apt install foo-new
```

and

```
apt install foo-old
```

would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible, you have to use a dummy transitional package which depends on foo-new. For a real world example see iceweasel package, which installs firefox now: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/iceweasel